# Pressure levels inside rocket liquid oxygen tanks?

Tags: rockets, fuel, pressure

What is the pressure levels inside rocket liquid oxygen tanks, at launch time?

The question is for the minimum and maximum (known) levels of pressure inside such tanks.

I am asking for any rocket since such data is not really easy to find.

If the pressure inside Atlas V is X, then the pressure for Delta V should be similar, or at least in the same order of magnitude.

Similar questions:

- [Pressure level inside Falcon 9 tanks?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49548/pressure-level-inside-falcon-9-tanks)
- [How does tank pressurization work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20648/how-does-tank-pressurization-work)?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Flight Manual](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a65f313edaed8c2a7e5cdf4/t/5cc235c08627c50001b1bfcf/1556231639562/Apollo+8+-+Saturn+V+flight+manual+-+Nov+1+1968.pdf), the Saturn V upper stage LOX tanks were maintained at 38-41 psi (2.6-2.8 bar).

The [first-stage LOX tanks](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap10fj/pdf/19700015780_as-505-a10-saturn-v-technical-info-summary.pdf) were kept at lower pressure, 20-24 psi (1.4-1.7 bar).

It appears those values may have varied slightly on different flights.

Comment: Why the pressure is higher în the second stage?

Comment: Different engine designs, J-2 on the upper stages, F-1 on the lower. I don't know why the engines were designed for different inlet pressures.

Comment: Interesting. First stage ~ same as shuttle.

Comment: Why is the pressure not higher in all stages; isn't more propellant better?  Or is the pressure largely a function of the volume/geometry of the storage vessel due to liquid oxygen being incompressible?

Comment: @aroth The pressure is maintained by supplied pressurant in the ullage above the liquid; it has little to do with the amount of propellant. Higher pressure = heavier structure = less payload (although some pressure stablizes the tank); the lowest pressure you can get away with is used.

Comment: I guess the hydrogen tanks have similar pressure levels. But how about kerosene? I guess it is very close to one bar?

Comment: I’ve provided links in my answer which can yield additional information.

Answer (score 4):

The ullage in the space shuttle external tank liquid oxygen tank was pressurized by ground-supplied  helium to its flight pressure level of **20-22 psig (1.4 - 1.5 bar)** at 2 minutes and 55 seconds before liftoff. Before that its vent/relief valve was open and the tank was approximately at ambient pressure. After liftoff ullage pressure was maintained at the same level by tapping gaseous oxygen from the space shuttle main engines.

[image]

Sources:

- [Shuttle Press Reference](https://archive.org/download/PressInformationSpaceShuttleTransportationSystemMarch1982/Press_Information_Space_Shuttle_Transportation_System_March_1982.pdf) pp. 92-95
- [Shuttle Countdown](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/countdown/count.html)