# Could a revised Space Shuttle be sent to the moon with a lander as cargo?

Tags: the-moon

Why couldn't a modernized and revised Space Shuttle with attached fuel tanks be used to go to the moon with a moon lander in it's cargo bay?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1829/58, https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12156/58

Comment: @GdD I don't know--that's not exactly a solid answer to a potential Shuttle 2.0, though perhaps the question leans toward being opinion based.

Comment: The linked answer covers it I think @called2voyage, a modernized shuttle would have the same challenges. There's nothing new here.

Comment: @GdD I thought that might be the case, but wasn't sure if it was a slam dunk. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!